# batch file unreachable script

Tags: msbuild, batch-file

I am new to batch scripting. Can someone help me with the following?

```
call %comspec% /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86
set MSBuildEmitSolution=1
msbuild "C:\Users\bleh\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\BuildApp\BuildApp.sln"
pause
```

This executes only the first line of the batch file, i.e. sets the VS environment.
Suggestions please.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `/k` in the first line with `/c`.  The `/k` switch to `cmd.exe` causes the command interpreter to run the command and await user input afterwards, whereas `/c` causes it to exit after running your command.